# How to add Office365 Owners group back to the associated SharePoint Owners group

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups

This is related to SharePoint Online site. (Template - TeamSite with Office365 group)

I've accidently deleted the associated SharePoint Owners group. Now I've created a new SharePoint Owners group.. everything ok. Hope you all aware of when a new site is created the Office365 groups get added to SharePoint Owners/Members groups.

Now how can I add the Office 365 group back to this new SP Owners group. I knew Office 365 Owners group (where the guid ends with _o) is hidden from UI so it can't be shown in UI. I tried with PowerShell and able to add it back with guid taken from Get-PnPUser. All good till now..

but Office 365 group is no longer hidden from UI. It's visible in groups.aspx page and in SP Owners group as well. Can't we hide this group from UI? (just wanted to make sure everything looks like OOB)
On a overall note adding the O365 group back like this causes any issue? Would this break anything?

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270114/office-365-group-owner-not-showing-in-sharepoint-group), seems there is "Hidden" property available with group. Try changing hidden property to true/yes and adding filter on it view as given in answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I tried.. I could not find Hidden property exposed for update... I could see the Hidden prop when I read all the properties...